# AS3 Error# 1009 Position Starts as null

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been having trouble when I run my code and Error # 1009 pops up which seems to stop my code from working. I believe that the problem is when my AddDalek() Function tries to assign a value to the x and y properties of the temporary object. However, I cannot figure out how to solve this problem. A solution and an explanation as to what the solution changes would be helpful.

This code is just the beginning of a game I am making for school so feel free to recommend any changes to my code.

For reference Cybermen, All Daleks, Silence, and Weeping Angels are the linkage to symbols

```
    import flash.events.*
    import flash.display.*

    var currentx = 229.95;
    var currenty = 429.6;
    var enemyspeed = 1;

    function randRange(min:Number, max:Number):Number {
        var randomNum:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    function AddCyberman (){
    var tempobject:Cyberman = new Cyberman();
    addChild (tempobject);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
    }

    function AddSilence (){
    var tempobject:Silence = new Silence();
    addChild (tempobject);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
    }

    function AddWeepingAngel (){
    var i = randRange(1,2);
    if (i == 1)
{
    var tempobject:WeepingAngel1 = new WeepingAngel1 ();
    addChild (tempobject);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
}

else if (i == 2)
{
    var tempobject1:WeepingAngel2 = new WeepingAngel2 ();
    addChild (tempobject1);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
}
    }

    function AddDalek()
    {
var i = randRange (1,5);
if (i == 1)
{
    var tempobject:BlueDalek = new BlueDalek ();
    addChild (tempobject);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
}
else if (i == 2)
{
    var tempobject1:YellowDalek = new YellowDalek ();
    addChild (tempobject1);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
}
else if (i == 3)
{

    var tempobject2:RedDalek = new RedDalek ();
    addChild (tempobject2);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
}
else if (i == 4)
{
    var tempobject3:GreenDalek = new GreenDalek ();
    addChild (tempobject3);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
}
else if (i == 5)
{
    var tempobject4:SilverDalek = new SilverDalek ();
    addChild (tempobject4);
    tempobject.x = currentx;
    tempobject.y = currenty;
}
    }

    function moveEnemys()
    {
var templist2:Array = new Array()
var templist:Array = [Silence , Cyberman , WeepingAngel1 , WeepingAngel2 , BlueDalek , YellowDalek , RedDalek , GreenDalek , SilverDalek];
for (var i = 0; i < templist.length; i++)
{
    if (templist[i])
    {
        templist2.push (templist[i]);
    }
}
for (var t = 0; t < templist2.length; i++)
{
    templist2[t].y += enemyspeed;
}
    }

    addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME , function() {OnFrameReset()});

    function OnFrameReset ()
    {
moveEnemys();
    }

    AddDalek();



    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object  reference.
at com.tylerkasper::Engine/AddDalek()
at com.tylerkasper::Engine/frame1()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your addDalek function, in the elses statements you still keep targeting tempobject as it don't exists. Try this:

```
function AddDalek()
{
    var i = randRange (1,5);
    if (i == 1)
    {
        var tempobject:BlueDalek = new BlueDalek ();
        addChild (tempobject);
        tempobject.x = currentx;
        tempobject.y = currenty;
    }
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        var tempobject1:YellowDalek = new YellowDalek ();
        addChild (tempobject1);
        tempobject1.x = currentx;
        tempobject1.y = currenty;
    }
    else if (i == 3)
    {

        var tempobject2:RedDalek = new RedDalek ();
        addChild (tempobject2);
        tempobject2.x = currentx;
        tempobject2.y = currenty;
    }
    else if (i == 4)
    {
        var tempobject3:GreenDalek = new GreenDalek ();
        addChild (tempobject3);
        tempobject3.x = currentx;
        tempobject3.y = currenty;
    }
    else if (i == 5)
    {
        var tempobject4:SilverDalek = new SilverDalek ();
        addChild (tempobject4);
        tempobject4.x = currentx;
        tempobject4.y = currenty;
    }
}
```

when you have errors on your code try debug the movie (ctrl+shift+enter) instead of just running it (ctrl+enter), you will have better error information and the line corresponding of the error.

Hope this will help you ;)

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe that it was such a simple mistake. Also, thank you for the information on debugging in the future. It really helps.